# Check if given output is correct in Gitlab CI

Tags: python, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I have switched to Gitlab and are using their CI functions. It it possible to check of the program output is correct?

For example, if I put the .py below into the CI, can I check if the output is "Hello World"?

```
print("Hello World")
```

If the CI detects that the program has not printed "Hello World", is it possible to make the test fail?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
script:
  - if ! [[ $(./test.py) == 'Hello World' ]]; then exit 1; fi
```